# Убрать лишние dots в Own Corousel

Tags: javascript, html

День добрый, есть карусель и в ней 8 элементов. При прокрутке к последнему элементу появляются лишние квадратики, как их убрать ? Пример: http://joxi.ru/gmvEJePTvq8KGr

```
$('.project-carousel').owlCarousel({
        margin:30,
        smartSpeed:150,
        dots:true,
        responsiveRefreshRate:0,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            768:{
                items:1
            },
            992:{
                items:1
            },
            1200:{
                items:4
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Просто так они не могут появляться. Точно лишних блоков не поставили?

Comment: Нет, 8 модальных окон и 8 каруселей

Comment: http://joxi.ru/DmBdWEoCzJ5MRA и http://joxi.ru/8An8L0Pc7zX6Km

Comment: вопрос решен. Из-за не внимательности потерял закрывающий тег div